# Diamond symbol hidden on communities list

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, moderators

For a long time, I've relied on the diamond symbol next to the stack exchange links of a user's community list to see which *(if any)* site a user moderates, like this *(Tim Post's communities)*:

[image]

But if the site name is long enough, the diamond gets hidden, hence it took my by surprise that Grundy is a moderator on [ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators):

[image]

Could the diamond symbol be still visible when the site name is long?

Comment: `<span class="modflair">` could indeed simply be moved out of its parent element, maybe with some margin added to it.

Comment: I had this problem as well, for now just _click on the link_.

Comment: This should definitely be fixed. Although I can't decide whether the diamond (mod flair) should *always* be shown, or only shown on hover along with the badges.